# Elixir EXRM upgrade No /relup file found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, exrm

Building and upgrading on Ubuntu 14.04

```
release 0.0.2 is already unpacked, now installing.
escript: exception error: no case clause matching
       {error,{enoent,"/home/user/user/rel/project/releases/0.0.1/relup"}}
```

There is no default rel/relx.config file as stated in the docs

Exrm version 1.0.8

The same thing for Distillery 0.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the old versions? That error is saying that it can't find version 0.0.1, so it has nothing to upgrade from.

You need to leave the previous version of the exrm deployment on your server in order to upgrade.

Comment: Yes. I've got all version there. The contents of 0.0.1 version directory are:
`project.bat
project.boot
project.rel
project.script
project.sh
project.tar.gz
start.boot
start_clean.boot
sys.config
vm.args
vm.args.orig`